# How to unit test methods posted by Event Bus in android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I am using Otto's event bus in my application. In one of my classes I am posting the event.

```
MyEvent myevent = new MyEvent();
uiBus.post(myEvent);
```

I am able to test the post method.

Now there is another class which is receiving the event.

```
//ReceiverClass.java
@Subscribe
public void onEventReceived(MyEvent myevent) {
    callAMethod();
}
```

How do I unit test that this method was invoked. I tried with the following test code

```
@Mock
Bus uiBus;

@Test
public void testBusReceviedEvent() {
    ReceiverClass instance = new ReceiverClass();
    mockBus.register(instance);
    MyEvent myevent = new MyEvent();
    mockBus.post(myEvent);
    //Test
    verify(instance, times(1)).callAMethod();
}
```

But this code doesn't work.

Comment: what is mockBus?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little late to the party but here is an example of a class which works and accounts for async calls.  Instead of Mocking EventBus we simply let it do it's thing and register it in the `TestDriver` class below.

The thing that makes this work is the `CountDownLatch` which, with the help of the abstract `DataTransferCallback` class, waits for `latch.countDown()` to be called or 5 seconds to go by.

Just register your test class and in the @Subscribe method, pass it back to the method that created the `DataTransferCallback` and do your assertions there.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class TestDriver {

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    private EventBus eventBus;

    private DataTransferCallback transferCallback;

    public abstract class DataTransferCallback {
        abstract void onSuccess(DataTransfer event);
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        eventBus = spy(EventBus.getDefault());
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Test
    public void test200Resposne() throws InterruptedException {
    // Get known good JSON
    final String json = TestJSON.get200Response();
    // Class under test
    final Driver driver = new Driver(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext());
    final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    //boolean to hold our test result
    final boolean[] testPassed = new boolean[]{false};

    transferCallback = new DataTransferCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DataTransfer event) {
            assertNotNull(event);
            verify(eventBus).post(event);
            assertThat(event.getStatus(), is("OK"));
            assertTrue(event.getData() != null);
            testPassed[0] = true;
        }
    };

    //Set our test EventBus object
    driver.setEventBus(eventBus);
    // The actual method under test
    driver.parseData(jsonParser.parse(json));

    // Set a countdown latch to wait for the result (5s)
    latch.await(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // will wait here until 5s or the @Subscrube method is hit
    assertTrue(testPassed[0]);
}

//Because we want to examine EventBus Output, register it 
//to this class and pass the event back through our custom abstract class
@Subscribe
public void onReceiveEventBusEvent(DataTransfer event) {
    assertNotNull(transferCallback);
    transferCallback.onSuccess(event);
    //notify latch so that we can proceed
    latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because `instance` is not a mock. You will have to verify the effects of `callAMethod` or put that method in another class and inject a mock of this new class into your `ReceiverClass` class.

For example...

```
private class ReceiverClass {
    private MyNewClass theNewClassIWasTalkingAbout;

    // Stick in a setter for that ^

    @Subscribe
    public void onEventReceived(MyEvent myevent) {
        theNewClassIWasTalkingAbout.callAMethod();
    }
}
```

Then your test will have to change slightly...

```
@Mock
private MyNewClass mockNewClass;

@InjectMocks // This will be the "solid" implementation of the thing you are trying to test, it is not a mock...
private ReceiverClass instance;

@Test
public void testBusReceivedEvent() {
    mockBus.register(instance);
    MyEvent myevent = new MyEvent();

    mockBus.post(myevent);

    verify(mockNewClass, times(1)).callAMethod();
}
```

Hope this helps.